# When is 'If P, Q' true

Tags: logic

I am a linguist and not a mathematician. If I was an expert mathematician, I wouldn't need your help.

In response to a query in a comment about when *if P, Q* is true, I recently was told by @amWhy:

- "If P then Q" (P→Q) is true whenever P is false, or Q is true (or both).

This was in response to a comment on this question here:

- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2572210/multiples-of-49

(You will only be able to see this post if you have a very large reputation score)

Now this interpretation is one of many mathematical (not all very simple) interpretations of when *If P, Q* is true. What I would like to know is whether the following sentence is true, if it is said about a particular number which as been written down on a specific piece of paper:

- If the number written on the paper is divisible by 9, it is divisible by 3.

In particular, suppose the number which is written on the paper is 4, is the sentence true?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth -- in particular the example "if $2\gt5$ then $2\gt3$."

Comment: This seems to be duplicate of the question you linked to, which itself was marked a duplicate of an earlier question of yours.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I don't understand Matthew. How is this question a duplicate of whether a number divisible by 7 and also a square number is divisible by 49?

Comment: yes, if the number that is written, say $x$, is divisible by $9$ then it is also divisible by $3$, if $x$ is not divisible then $x$ may or may not be divisible by $3$. if $x$ is a constant that is not divisible by $9$ then this is vacuous truth, the statement is about an empty set(written on the paper$\land$divisible by 9) so it has to be true

Comment: See: [Assumed True until proven False.  The Curious Case of the Vacuous Truth](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439987/assumed-true-until-proven-false-the-curious-case-of-the-vacuous-truth?rq=1)

Comment: *If the number written on the paper is divisible by 9, it is divisible by 3.* In your last supposition, "suppose the number which is written on the paper is 4, is the sentence true?"  **Yes**, the sentence is true.  The only case in which an implication is false is when the antecedent is true, but the conclusion is false. All the other three truth value assignments make the conditional true.

Comment: This is the the definition of the conditional $P\to Q$.  Yes, I know we want relevance, cause and effect, etc (as often implied in natural language).  But mathematically/logically $P\to Q$ is defined to be true **unless** P is true, and Q is false.  Not necessarily intuitive, but that is the definition.

Comment: You write: "Now this interpretation is one of many mathematical (not all very simple) interpretations of when If P, Q is true." This is incorrect. The statement "If P, Q" has exactly one interpretation in mathematics. Unsurprisingly, it is sometimes interpreted differently in natural language, but that's not at issue here.

Comment: @AlexKruckman `Unsurprisingly, it is sometimes interpreted differently in natural language, but that's not at issue here.` Except the OP is `a linguist and not a mathematician`, as they wrote, and there appears to be some crosstalk between the two here.

Comment: @dxiv I understand that, and I think the crosstalk between the two is exactly the problem - in a sense, that was the point of my comment. If the OP is going to ask mathematicians what "if then" statements mean in mathematics, the OP should be prepared to discard their prior notions of what "if then" statements mean in natural language.

Comment: @Araucaria: I think you are confusing a lot of people because you quote a definition of "if P then Q" which immediately answers your question, so it is unclear what exactly you feel you are missing.  I think (but am not sure) that your misconception is that you believe "if P then Q" can have multiple different meanings in mathematics and so are asking about those other meanings, but this is just totally false as Alex Kruckman said.

Comment: You may be interested in [this blog post](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/basic-logic-connectives-implies/) by Tim Gowers. @Araucaria

Comment: Hint: We have: $\neg 3\mid 4$ and $\neg 9 \mid 4$

Comment: Hint: By the contrapositive rule, we also have:  $9\mid 4 \implies 3\mid 4 \space \equiv \space \neg 3 \mid 4 \implies \neg 9 \mid 4$. Both are true.

Answer (score 1):

If the number that is written, say $x$, is divisible by $9$ then it is also divisible by $3$. If $x$ is not divisible by $9$, then $x$ may or may not be divisible by $3$, so in this case this is true statement.

If $x$ is a constant that is not divisible by $9$ then this is [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth). The statement is about an empty set (written on the paper $\land$ divisible by 9), so it has to be true.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you saw a sign one evening:

> If you wear jeans then you will not be allowed inside this concert hall.

Would you question the truth of the statement just because no one around you is wearing jeans?

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. -1

Comment: @Araucaria Guess we'll have to agree to disagree on that. IMHO this directly answers the question as literally written. If you had a different question in mind then by all means spell that out better in the main post.

Comment: @Araucaria The truth value of the statement does not depend on the choice of the free variables, and I believe that's where your confusion lies. In your case, the statement is true regardless of what number is written on the paper. In my answer, the statement is true regardless of who is wearing what, or even whether there are any spectators lined up at all.

Comment: `anything follows from something that isn't true` Correct, that's for example why [inconsistent theories are complete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582542/any-inconsistent-theory-must-be-complete). `but you didn't say any of that` Right, the point was to put forward an example along the same line as yours, only pushed to the extreme where (I thought) it became self-evident what the answer was and why.